# Can't update manifest.mf inside .jar: line too long error

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf

I have one .jar file with only MANIFEST/MANIFEST.MF file inside it. I want to extend classpath in this file. Already googled on how to do this and found this:

1. Extract MANIFEST/MANIFEST.MF - `jar xf myfile.jar
   MANIFEST/MANIFEST.MF`
2. Edit manifest file
3. Update it inside .jar - `jar umf myfile.jar MANIFEST/MANIFEST.MF`

The problem is that I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: line too long
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:379)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.update(Main.java:652)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:271)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

Google says that maximum line length of manifest is 72 - OK. Tried not to edit  extracted manifest file. When I try to import the same file I just extracted I get the same error. Maybe there's a tool that formats manifest files in order to make them "valid"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update command should be:

```
jar umf MANIFEST/MANIFEST.MF myfile.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below steps to avoid the issue

(1) use separate lines, to avoid too long a line for java package name lists

(2) (Space at the end of each line and one at the beginning) . Type a preceding space before each following lines, for example: Class-Path: ...jar ...jar ...jar